# HTTP Request returning 403 under Heroku

Tags: python, heroku

Long story short, I'm trying to load a page and then parse the content of it (basically scraping it).

This is the base code I'm using:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://etherscan.io'
html = requests.get(url)

print(html.status_code)
```

In my machine this piece of code returns 200 which is great but when I run the same code under Heroku for some reason it returns 403.

I already tried the same code with other sites and they work fine under Heroku but I don't know why it fails specifically when requesting etherscan.io.

Also tried changing the http headers with no difference.

Any idea what could be the culprit?

Comment: Do they provide an error message?

Comment: It's very possible that they have protection in place to prevent such behaviour. Have you read their acceptable use policy? Do they want you to scrape their data?

Comment: @TomMarienfeld heroku logs shows no error.

Comment: @Chris It's possible they have some kind of protection but my sixth sense tells me I'm probably missing something.

Comment: @stuckinplace, it's still a good idea to check (and follow) their acceptable use policy.